# How to remove all traces of curl installed using libcurl package (.tar.gz)

Tags: php, curl

I have installed curl package in ubuntu 12.04. I tried the `sudo apt-get install php5-curl` method but it did not work.

I downloaded the `curl-7.37.1.tar.gz` package from http://curl.haxx.se/download.html and extracted it and followed [How do I install a .tar.gz (or .tar.bz2) file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-do-i-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file#answer-1030) to install a .tar.gz file.

I am not able to configure it to work with apache. How can I remove it so that I can install `curl` using `apt-get`?

Comment: Please include a link to exactly what file you downloaded and the guide you followed.

Answer (score 3):

inside curl directory where you made `sudo make install` just do `sudo make uninstall`

Answer (score 0):

Use `locate curl` command to find and then delete executable ***curl*** file and shell script ***curl-config*** file. In my case they were in usr/local/bin folder